# Когда использую float, теряется высота родителя

Tags: css, float

Встретился с проблемой: когда у всех дочерних элементов указал float, то у родителя потерялась высота, т.е. ушла в 0px.

*Пример:*

```css
.parent {
  width: 162px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.children {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

Почему родитель перестал учитывать высоту дочерних элементов? Как исправить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Родитель перестал учитывать высоту дочерних элеметов потом, что элементы с float создают новый контекст наложения и выпадают из потока элементов.

**Есть четыре варианта решения вашего вопроса:**

1. Если у всех дочерних элементов фиксированная высота, то и у родителя указываем фиксированную высоту:

   ```css
   .parent {
     width: 162px;
     border: 2px solid red;
     /* Фиксированная высота */
     height: 54px;
   }
   .children {
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     border: 2px solid blue;
     float: left;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="parent">
     <div class="children"></div>
     <div class="children"></div>
     <div class="children"></div>
   </div>
   ```
2. Самый распространённый вариант ― **clearfix**. Создаём отдельный элемент или псевдоэлемент со стилем `cler: both;`:

   ```css
   .parent {
     width: 162px;
     border: 2px solid red;
   }
   .children {
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     border: 2px solid blue;
     float: left;
   }

   /* Clearfix */
   .clearfix {
     display: table;
     clear: both;
     visibility: hidden;
   }

   .parent.b:after {
     content: '';
     display: table;
     clear: both;
     visibility: hidden;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <p>С элементом:</p>

   <div class="parent a">
     <div class="children"></div>
     <div class="children"></div>
     <div class="children"></div>
     
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
   </div>

   <p>С псевдоэлементом:</p>

   <div class="parent b">
     <div class="children"></div>
     <div class="children"></div>
     <div class="children"></div>
   </div>
   ```
3. Один из самых интересных, но недейственных вариантов ― указать родителю float и тогда он тоже выпадет из общего потока и "соединится" с дочерними элементами:

   ```css
   .parent {
     width: 162px;
     border: 2px solid red;
     /* Float */
     float: left;
   }
   .children {
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     border: 2px solid blue;
     float: left;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="parent">
     <div class="children"></div>
     <div class="children"></div>
     <div class="children"></div>
   </div>
   ```
4. И последний вариант ― указать родителю overflow. Overflow создаёт отдельный контекст форматирования для выбранного элемента, тем самым локализуя действие свойства float внутри элемента к которому применён. [Подробнее...](https://habrahabr.ru/post/48383/)

   ```css
   .parent {
     width: 162px;
     border: 2px solid red;
     /* Overflow */
     overflow: auto;
     /* Можно устанавливать следущие значения:
        auto, hidden, overlay, scroll
     */
   }
   .children {
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     border: 2px solid blue;
     float: left;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="parent">
     <div class="children"></div>
     <div class="children"></div>
     <div class="children"></div>
   </div>
   ```